# Linq2Sql - Storing Complex Linq Queries for future dynamic execuction - raw text - possible?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am having a lot of fun with Linq2Sql. Expression Trees have been great, and just the standard Linq2Sql syntax has been a lot of fun.

I am now down to part of my application where I have to somehow store queries in a database, that are custom for different customers that use the same database and same tables (well, view, but you know what I mean). Basically, I cant hard-code anything, and I have to leave the query language clear text so someone can write a new where-clause type query.

So, if that description was harsh, let me clarify:

In a previous version of our application, we used to do direct SQL calls to the db using raw SQL.  Yea. it was fun, dirty, and it worked.   We would have a database table fulled of different criteria like

```
(EventType = 6 and Total > 0)
```

or a subquery style

```
(EventType = 7 
AND Exists (
    select * 
    from events as e1 
        where events.EventType = e1.EventType 
        and e1.objectNumber = 89)
    )
```

(sql injection anyone?)

In Linq2Sql, this is a little more challenging.  I can make all these queries no problem in the CLR, but being able to pass dynamic where criterias to Linq is a little more challenging, especially if I want to perform a sub query (like the above example).

Some ideas I had:

Get the raw expression, and store it --- but I have no idea how to take the raw text expression and reverse it back to executable to object expression.

Write a SQl like language, and have it parse the code and generate Linq Expression -- wow, that could be a lot of fun

I am quite sure there is no `SomeIqueryable.Where("EventType = 6 and Total > 54")`. I was reading that it was available in beta1, but I don't see how you can do that now.

```
var exp2 = context.POSDataEventView.Where("EmployeeNumber == @0", 8310);
```

This would be the easiest way for me to deploy.. I think.

Store serialized Expressions -- wow.. that would be confusing to a user trying to write a query --- hell, I'm not sure I could even type it all out.

So, I am looking for some ideas on how I can store a query in some kind of clear text, and then execute it against my Linq2Sql objects in some fashion without calling the ExecuteSQL. I want to use the LinqObjects.

P.S. I am using pLinqo for this application if that helps.  Its still linq2sql though.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the [Dynamic LINQ Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) (in the MSDN samples) would help?

In particular, usage like:
[image: .Where("Category=2 And UnitPrice>3"]

This should work with any `IQueryable<T>` source - including LINQ-to-Objects simply by calling `.AsQueryable()` on the sequence (typically `IEnumerable<T>`).

Comment: So, we are very close with this.  However, after running some tests on it, it doesn't appear that you can throw in a sub query. You will get things like:

No property or field 'select' exists in type 'DataEventView'

Has anyone used the Dynamic Linq extension with a sub query yet?

Here is an example:

posQuery = posQuery.Where("exists ( select * from DataEventView as E1 where E1.DataTimeSTamp > t0.DataTimeStamp and E1.DataTimeStamp < DateAdd(mi, 5, t0.DataTimeStamp) and EventTypeID = 7 and E1.CheckNumber = t0.CheckNumber )");

Comment: Because nobody chimed in for sub queries, I wrote Scott Gu, and he had me work with one of his guys.   There were a couple options, but I am still working out the details.

Comment: Did anything ever happen with this?

Comment: I was wondering if Travis ever came to completion on the sub queries work with Scott's team

Comment: Sorry, I wish StackOverflow would notify me of these follow up messages. I actually did come up with a unique way to handle this. I offered two different methods in my application for running a query. Once I classified as a simple query where it just made use of the dynamic query support. The other was a bit more complex.  I actually stored string Linq code using a query expression or linq string that accessed my DataContext.  When the user would request to see this, I would dynamically compile the Linq expression in memory and that would give me an IQueryable<> base to query with subqueries.

Comment: The comment section is to short to type up the entire solution.  Scotts team also turned me onto writing Expression Trees. Those are cool, but way to complex for an end user to understand.  If you want to sub queries, you have to get tricky but its rewarding when its done.  Sorry I didn't reply sooner.   This accepted answer did lead me to a creative solution however, even if it didn't support everything i needed.

Comment: @Travis there *is* notification, but only if you use the `@someone` convention; otherwise, the system assumes it is directed at *me*