# Linq2Sql - Storing Linq Expressions in cleartext (linq) for future dynamic execution

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I recently posted this:

[[Linq2Sql - Storing Complex Linq Queries for future dynamic execuction - raw text - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558269/linq2sql-storing-complex-linq-queries-for-future-dynamic-execuction-raw-text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558269/linq2sql-storing-complex-linq-queries-for-future-dynamic-execuction-raw-text)

It answered one question, but sent me down a different path because of the subQuery needing to reference the same table the original query already exists in.

I was able to do exactly what I wanted to do in Linqpad using the "let" keyword.

from posMain in DataEventView
let posSub = from posSub1 in DataEventView where posSub1.CheckNumber == posMain.CheckNumber && posSub1.EventTypeID == 7 select posSub1
where posMain.EventTypeID == 6 && posSub.Any()
select posMain

That is effectively creating the sub-query I have been attempting to do.

Now, I was thinking --- I would really like to dynamically create the IQueryable object in memory, and then my application can have reference to it, and continue to add expressions to it as needed.

I am thinking I am going to have to do this with the CodeDom, but there may be a more elegant way of getting the IQueryable from just having Raw Text to start with.  Has anyone had to store a linq statement for future execution?  These statements are dynamic per customer, so they cant just be complied into the framework.  Maybe there is a better idea?

Thanks in advance.

Travis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this blog post has what you are looking to do:

http://igorshare.wordpress.com/2008/01/11/codedom-extensions-and-dynamic-linq-stringscript-to-linq-emitting/

Answer (score 0):

You may use Expression Trees.

Some sampels are provided [here](http://rapidapplicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/03/expression-trees-why-linq-to-sql-is.html)

Comment: Thats not really what I am trying to do.  Expression Trees are easy. I'm trying to figure out how to store a linq statement as clear text, and then execute it on demand against some valid expressions in memory, and then continue to use the IQueryable after the clear text has been executed. Clear text meaning the whole linq statement written out in human readable.  Thanks though.